# How to work with `numpy.timedelta64` outside of pandas/numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

From a pandas DataFrame, when I extract the value of a specific `timedelta` field, I receive an object of type `numpy.timedelta64`:

```
>>> numpy_delta
numpy.timedelta64(-2700000000000,'ns')
```

I understand that this is numpy's representation for "-2700000000000 Nanoseconds". How can I create an object `datetime.timedelta` from that numpy object to use it outside of numpy?
From my expectations, that solution should provide:

```
>>> datetime_timedelta
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=83700)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with `datetime64` dtype arrays, `tolist()` or `item()` do a good job of converting the array to base Python objects.  Let's try that with your timedelta:

```
In [174]: x=np.timedelta64(-2700000000000,'ns')
In [175]: x.item()
Out[175]: -2700000000000
```

Not quite what we want.  But if I first convert it to minutes:

```
In [176]: x.astype('timedelta64[m]')
Out[176]: numpy.timedelta64(-45,'m')
In [177]: x.astype('timedelta64[m]').item()
Out[177]: datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=83700)
```

Comment: Hey @hpaulj, thanks for your contribution!
From the demo code you shared, that 'hack' obviously works, but having the solution right before my eyes, I still do not get it: Why does `x.item()` return a `int`, while a `numpy.timedelta64`, that got converted to "minutes", returns a `datetime.timedelta`?

Comment: I haven't studied the relevant `c` code

Comment: I do not mean how the backend code performs these conversions - I mean: I'd like to get the logic behind that. How would I come to an idea like that next time without StackOverflow? ;)
Did you find this in any Doc? Or: Where do YOU know it works like this from?

Comment: I just experimented.  I knew from past use that the `datetime64` dtype produced `datetime` lists, so expected the `timedelta` to behave similarly.  I don't know why the smallest units unpacks to an integer.  The implementation of datetimes in `numpy` is relatively new and in need of improvement.  `matplotlib` has been handling dates for some time.  `pandas` may also be more consistent.